# Edit variable in function then recall edited variable in another function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, arkit

I want to preface this with I am a beginner to Swift but need to get this ARKit project finished already.

I use the function.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    let trackedNode = node
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
       if (imageAnchor.isTracked) {
           trackedNode.isHidden = false
           offScreen = false
           print("Visible")
        }else {
           trackedNode.isHidden = true
           //print("\(trackedImageName)")
           offScreen = true
           print("No image in view")
       }
    }
 }
```

This detects if the anchor is on screen and sets the global variable `offScreen` to the appropriate value.

I want to take the new value of the variable and use it in my `createdVideoPlayerNodeFor` function. If offScreen is true, then set AVPlayer to pause.

However, I have my AVPlayer declared in my `createdVideoPlayerNodeFor` function so I can't contain it in one function.

I know I am referring to fragments of my code at a time so I have full code posted below.

```
var offScreen = false

    let videoNode = SCNNode()

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        offScreen = false

        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

        node.addChildNode(createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(referenceImage))

    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        let trackedNode = node

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{

        if (imageAnchor.isTracked) {
            trackedNode.isHidden = false
            offScreen = false
            print("Visible")

        }else {
            trackedNode.isHidden = true
            //print("\(trackedImageName)")
            offScreen = true
            print("No image in view")
        }
      }
    }

    func createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(_ target: ARReferenceImage) -> SCNNode {

        let videoPlayerGeometry = SCNPlane(width: target.physicalSize.width, height: target.physicalSize.height)
        var player = AVPlayer()

        if let targetName = target.name,
            let awsURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "my video url :).mp4") {
            player = AVPlayer(url: awsURL as URL)
            player.play()

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                        player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                        player.pause()
            }

    }


                         videoPlayerGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = player
                         videoNode.geometry = videoPlayerGeometry
                         videoNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
                         return videoNode
    }
```

I am in dire need of help with this so if anyone can help me to figure this out, It would be greatly appreciated.

Please ask questions if I didn't explain well enough or anything, I really just need to figure this out :)

Edit: In my testing, I found that when the variable was changed in either function, it was almost like the variable had 2 different values, 1 for each of the functions. So if it was set to true in the `didUpdate` function, it didn't matter because the `createdVideo` function would use the value set at the beginning of the variable's declaration. Is this even possible to set the value of the variable in one func and have it carry over to another?

Answer (score 0):

`offScreen` is an instance variable, which means that it is in scope for both functions. You should be able to both read and set it from either. Be careful, however, that you don't read/write that variable from *different threads* as then the value can be unpredictable. You might want to set up an `offscreenQueue`, a private `DispatchQueue`, that will restrict access to this variable.